# Consul Template variable assinging with condition

Tags: haproxy, consul, consul-template

I have to assign some variable depending on other variable and some conditions

I've tried to code this but with no luck

```
{{- $region_for_link := $region}}
{{- if eq $region "a"}} {{- $region_for_link := "AAA"}} {{- end}}
{{- if eq $region "b"}} {{- $region_for_link := "BBB"}} {{- end}}
```

I wanted to have value in `$region_for_link` `AAA` when `$region` is `a`, but after that `$region_for_link` is still  `a`. How to code that properly, probably it is obvious case, but I can't get it.

Please help, I'm waiting for your answer

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Consul-template uses a version of the Go Template engine.  According to the documentation at https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables :

> A pipeline inside an action may initialize a variable to capture the result. The initialization has syntax
>
> `$variable := pipeline`
>
> where $variable is the name of the variable. An action that declares a variable produces no output.
>
> Variables previously declared can also be assigned, using the syntax
>
> `$variable = pipeline`

The below code, resulted in printing of `AAA`:

```
{{ $region := "a" }}
{{- $region_for_link := $region}}
{{- if eq $region "a"}} {{- $region_for_link = "AAA"}} {{- end}}
{{- if eq $region "b"}} {{- $region_for_link = "BBB"}} {{- end}}
{{ $region_for_link }}
```